# Yii framework, assign different templates to different section

Tags: templates, yii

I'm developing a CMS for using Yii framework, the website has a frontend visible to everyone, and a backend for the logged in user. I have different templates for these two. However I don't know how to assign a different template to my backend.

Here is my config/main.php, and the template that I have added is applied to the whole website.

```
return array(

    'theme'=>'cola_theme',
    ...
);
```

Comment: Do you have a separate config file or an entire controller that deals with the backend?

Comment: No, I have only one. So, should I make separate config files? Can you explain more or refer me to a link? I'm pretty new with Yii...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use different themes, you can update the [theme](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#theme-detail) property of the webapp, with:

```
Yii::app()->theme = 'case_sensitive_theme_name';
```

Alternatively, if you just want to use a different layout, you can update the [layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail) property of your controller in the actions that are available for the backend ie:

```
$this->layout='//layouts/backend_layout';
```

Where the `layouts` folder is under `protected/views/`.

More on [theming](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming) and [layouts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#layout).